# ScheduledExecutorService multiple threads of same runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using java's ScheduledExecutorService to shedule a task that should run every 15 min. I use the following code

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(jobScheduler.getSomethingToDo(), 1, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Locally everything is perfect but when I run this in production over an extended period of time I can see in the thread dumps that sometimes there is more than one somethingToDo thread. I have wrapped the whole run method of the runnable in a try/catch block. What my be wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that you create multiple schedulers with the code above? or maybe you are running the somethingToDo task from other places in your code?

Comment: Maybe post the thread dump showing the 2 stacks with `somethingToDo()` running

Comment: make sure you are not calling this method (of scheduling ```jobScheduler.getSomethingToDo()```) twice. It will create as many ```scheduledExecutorService``` as the number of times this code block is called

Comment: The method is only being called once. I made sure. jobScheduler.getSomethingToDo is only been called once, I also made sure using IntelliJ usages function